# Display Suite Extra options not showing up

Tags: 8, display-suite

I installed and activated the "Display Suite Extra" module. But the menu point "Custom CSS classes" under "Manage display" of any content type is missing.

What else do I need to activate the Display Suite Extra features in Drupal 8? I already uninstalled and activated the module but the features of the Extra module are still missing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Display Suite is third party and this sounds like a bug which you should report with steps to reproduce while including the versions of Drupal and the module and other dependencies you used to Display Suite's issue queue on drupal.org, not here.

Comment: If it is a bug. I'm not sure maybe I just misunderstood something... and I need to activate the extra features somewhere.